# How can I strip attachments in old Gmail email?

Tags: gmail, attachment

I have a load of messages with attachments. I want to keep the email but get rid of the attachments. This will free-up a load of space.

Comment: Are you really running out of space on Gmail? I've used it for everything for years now and I'm still only at 20% usage...

Answer (score 6):

I think what you'll need to do is forward the message to yourself without the attachment, and then delete the original message. **Just** the message, mind you, not the entire thread. You do that by clicking the down arrow on the message and selecting "Delete this message".

[image: Gmail screenshot]

Comment: one at a time == slow.

Comment: I agree, but that's the only way to do it without using a third-party tool. Even then I'm not so sure you can batch it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a desktop client such as Thunderbird with an IMAP connection to your Gmail account. [Step by step guide here.](http://exde601e.blogspot.com/2011/05/remove-attachments-from-gmail.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try [this Google Docs script](http://techawakening.org/delete-attachments-from-gmail-without-deleting-the-emails/1842/), it worked for me. It does not require installing anything.