# What to do when Gmail runs out of space?

Tags: gmail, backup

Of course, you can purchase more space at a reasonable price. Also, I've found [backupify](https://www.backupify.com/) and [findbigmail](https://www.findbigmail.com/), and there's the download via imap and delete option outlined, for example [here](http://www.labnol.org/internet/email/reclaim-lost-space-in-gmail-account/5747/).

What I really want is to download any large attachments to a back-up, and strip them from the emails, but leave the text of the message in place for searching. Any services that do that? Or any other ideas?

Comment: Closely related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17260/how-can-i-strip-attachments-in-old-gmail-email

Answer (score 8):

You have two options:

- forward the emails to yourself and remove the attachments when doing it (and afterwards delete the original emails); or
- use a desktop client to download the emails via IMAP and remove the attachments from them (not deleting the entire emails as is specified in the example you mentioned)  - Thunderbird and Outlook seem to allow it.

There is a thread on Gmail help dealing with this exact issue: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=2d69c50302cf0e14&hl=en

Answer (score 6):

Google has an engineering team known as the [Data Liberation Front](http://www.dataliberation.org/).

> ### The Data Liberation Front
>
> The Data Liberation Front is an engineering team at Google whose
> singular goal is to make it easier for users to move their data in and
> out of Google products.  We do this because we believe that you should
> be able to export any data that you create in (or import into) a
> product.  We help and consult other engineering teams within Google on
> how to "liberate" their products.  This is our mission statement:
>
> ***Users should be able to control the data they store in any
> of Google's products.  Our team's goal is to make it easier to move
> data in and out.***

The [specific information on Gmail says](http://www.dataliberation.org/google/gmail) that IMAP is the preferred choice for liberation (or backup in your case). Almost all email clients will support IMAP (or POP if not).

> ### Escaping from Gmail
>
> #### IMAP, POP Access
>
> It's easy to use a different email reading program with Gmail using
> either IMAP or POP, or to get all your mail out to take to a different
> provider.  Go to the Settings page (link at top right of Gmail page),
> Forwarding and POP/IMAP tab.
>
> This tab lets you set up POP and IMAP, with instructions for popular
> email reading programs.  There is extensive online help available for
> both POP and IMAP.

Comment: The Data Liberation Front site now redirects to a Google Accounts Help Center article.