# Gmail account is full and can not free space by deleting emails

Tags: gmail

Need help! My e-mail at work is at 99.9% full. I can’t delete anymore messages to free up space, and the storage that is available for sale through Google does not apply to Gmail.

What can I do to preserve 5 years worth of e-mails and continue using my account? Someone had suggested that I change the e-mail address on the current account and create a new one with my old e-mail address.

That way all the old e-mail will be stored and I will start fresh with my same old e-mail address. However, I do not see how that can be done, as the e-mail address itself can not be changed.

Comment: Is this a free 10GB Gmail account, or Google Apps for business 25GB account? If the former then you can upgrade to the later (at cost).

Answer (score 9):

The purchase options for Google storage include bonus Gmail storage in the cost. You can go [here](https://www.google.com/settings/storage/) to have a look, in essence both plans will boost your Gmail space to 25GB (plus you get the extra space on Google Drive of course).

Other things to try:

- You could check for huge emails or attachments taking up space (some methods in [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/22697/16377))
- Make sure your **Spam** and **Trash** folders are empty
- Download your emails using an email client like [Thunderbird](http://www.mozilla.org/thunderbird/) as describe in [this](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=34030) Google article

Google also have [a page on this topic](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1186436) with a number of suggestions - some included here and others more complex such as delegating the account to another.

Answer (score 8):

To find large emails use the relatively new [advanced search term](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=7190) **larger:5M** in the search box. It will find all emails larger than 5 Megabytes in size.

Answer (score 6):

You may consider this approach as well:

1. Use the larger:5mb search operator in Gmail to find the really big mails.
2. Apply the label "Google Drive" to the larger mails.
3. You can either save all these large attachments to your Google Drive using [Google Scripts](http://www.labnol.org/internet/send-gmail-to-google-drive/21236/) (and delete the original messages) or forward them all to another email address using another [Google Script](http://www.labnol.org/internet/auto-forward-gmail-messages/20665/).

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to indeed create another gmail account. In your OLD account you forward all messages to your new account AND automatically delete the incoming messages on your OLD account.

In your new account you ADD an alternative account, which is your OLD account and make that the default. This way you send messages from your new account with the credentials of your OLD account. All messages to your old account are automatically forwarded to your new account and since the messages in your old account are removed upon forwarding, there is no further accumulation.

How to forward EVERY new message, including spam?

Create a new filter in settings.
`Doesn't have` = Ð (or any other odd character or set of characters that you do NOT expect in  any message)
Click on `Continue`
Check the following categories:
Forward it to:
Delete it:
Never send it to Spam:

Your NEW Gmail account will work just as if it is your old account!

Answer (score 0):

Delete all obsolete and unimportant emails in the "social" tab, or "trash", "spam" and unnecessary files on your Google drive. 
You can also use Google One: Starting at 100 GB. The All Google Account includes 15 GB of storage free of charge .: https://one.google.com/storage
---
Besides Google One, you can compare Google Suite: 
https://gsuite.google.com/intl/en/pricing.html
---
Google script tips for the latest Gmail filters that are very suitable for you to try (for your problem): 
https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/apps-scripts-gmail-users/

Answer (score -1):

you may want to use https://www.findbigmail.com/ (if you are not influenced by http://www.scroogled.com/)