# Gmail getting full, does creating folders help clear inbox?

Tags: gmail

Gmail is getting full, does creating folders help that?

Comment: What do you mean by “full”? That you are getting closer to the 15 GB quota? Or that is cluttered?

Comment: Creating folder alone will not clear your inbox, you need to archive them to those created folders (labels). If you cleared your inbox, then you're left with the same "full" Gmail. You can buy extra storage.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about your storage quota, no.

Gmail doesn't have "folders". It has "labels". They're just like tags you can add to messages to help find them later. A message can have multiple labels. (Unlike a folder, where a message can only exist in one at a time.) "Moving" a message to a label will not free up any storage in Gmail.

If you want to free up some storage, [Running Out of Space on GMail, Now What?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22669/running-out-of-space-on-gmail-now-what) has some good suggestions. There's also help available from [Google Support](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6558?ref_topic=1669054).

You might also have a look at [Organizing your mail](https://support.google.com/mail/topic/1669016?ref_topic=1668946).