# When archiving Gmail email free up more space in Google Drive

Tags: gmail

When Archiving my email using Gmail does that help increase my storage in Google drive?  I have a Gmail account and I use Google Drive. I don't have a lot of pictures but I have used 11GB of my space.  At this rate I either have to buy more space or Delete my emails.

But if I archive them and they get stored somewhere else and free up my Google Drive that would be great.

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Answer (score 2):

No, I'm afraid you've misunderstood what "Archive" means in the context of Gmail.

"Archive" simply means "remove the 'Inbox' label" from a message/conversation. The original conceit of Gmail was that you really don't need to delete anything; you just need good search tools to find your old messages. At the time Gmail launched you got an unbelievable amount of space (at least, compared to other web mail services at the time).

[Gmail Help: Archive messages in Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6576)

To free up space in Gmail, you would need to actually delete messages. You could possibly use a third-party client and IMAP to move the messages to another mailbox so that you don't lose them, but that's a whole 'nother topic.

There are some other questions (and answers) here which you might find helpful:

- [What to do when Gmail runs out of space?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/17733/354)
- [How do I delete attachments, in bulk, from messages in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/51478/354)

Of course, you should check to ensure that it's Gmail that's using your space:

- [Google Drive storage mismatch](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/69184/354)